# SQL Sums in Rows Pulled out into Columns?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a search that is very slowly done by finding the primary records then looping in a thread to sum related transactions. I'm trying to make it work in a single statement, have come close but still have records which are alternating debit and credits.

**I can't work out how to pull the debit and credit rows up into columns so there is one row of results per date and jobke**y.

```
SELECT j.dtmInvoicedOn, j.strJobKey, c.strCustName, strTransType, 
     SUM(r.dblTransactionAmount) AS SUM_dblTotalCharge 
     FROM tbljobs AS j
     INNER JOIN tblreceivledger AS r ON j.strJobKey = r.strJobKey 
     INNER JOIN tblcustomers AS c ON j.intCustomerID = c.intCustomerID 
     WHERE c.strCustomerName = 'Acme Runners Inc'
     GROUP BY j.strJobKey, c.strCustName, strTransType
     ORDER BY dtmInvoicedOn, strJobKey;
```

produces output like this, with nearly alternating debit and credit sums

```
+----------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| dtmInvoicedOn  | strJobKey     | strCustomerName  | strTransactionType | SUM_dblTotalCharge |
+----------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 2008-07-03     | 270876-1      | Acme Runners Inc | credit             |           -5531.52 | 
| 2008-07-11     | 270880-1      | Acme Runners Inc | debit              |            5058.54 | 
| 2008-07-11     | 270880-1      | Acme Runners Inc | credit             |           -5058.54 | 
| 2008-07-18     | 271468-1      | Acme Runners Inc | debit              |            5290.17 | 
| 2008-07-18     | 271468-1      | Acme Runners Inc | credit             |           -5290.17 | 
| 2008-11-07     | 286049-1      | Acme Runners Inc | debit              |            5230.44 | 
| 2008-11-14     | 286051-1      | Acme Runners Inc | debit              |            5375.14 | 
| 2008-11-21     | 286107-1      | Acme Runners Inc | debit              |            5572.33 | 
| 2008-11-28     | 286112-1      | Acme Runners Inc | debit              |            5123.42 |
```

so I want it to look like:

```
+----------------+---------------+------------------+----------+----------+
| dtmInvoicedOn  | strJobKey     | strCustomerName  |   credit |    debit |
+----------------+---------------+------------------+----------+----------+
| 2008-07-03     | 270876-1      | Acme Runners Inc | -5531.52 |        0 |
| 2008-07-11     | 270880-1      | Acme Runners Inc | -5058.54 |  5058.54 | 
| 2008-07-18     | 271468-1      | Acme Runners Inc | -5290.17 |  5290.17 | 
| 2008-11-07     | 286049-1      | Acme Runners Inc |        0 |  5230.44 | 
| 2008-11-14     | 286051-1      | Acme Runners Inc |        0 |  5375.14 | 
| 2008-11-21     | 286107-1      | Acme Runners Inc |        0 |  5572.33 | 
| 2008-11-28     | 286112-1      | Acme Runners Inc          0 |  5123.42 |
```

Note that the server is currently running mysql but will migrate to postgres and sqlite later.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should do the job:

```
SELECT j.dtmInvoicedOn, j.strJobKey, c.strCustName, strTransType, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN strTransType='credit' THEN r.dblTransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_CREDIT,
     SUM(CASE WHEN strTransType='debit' THEN r.dblTransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_DEBIT
FROM tbljobs AS j
     INNER JOIN tblreceivledger AS r ON j.strJobKey = r.strJobKey 
     INNER JOIN tblcustomers AS c ON j.intCustomerID = c.intCustomerID 
WHERE c.strCustomerName = 'Acme Runners Inc'
GROUP BY j.strJobKey, c.strCustName
ORDER BY dtmInvoicedOn, strJobKey;
```

Comment: I was obfuscating the query as my boss has been strict on never releasing actual schema details in any public discussions, typo fixed thanks. Thanks for the hint - I use a lot of CASE statements in other contexts, hadn't thought of putting inside a SUM!

Answer (score 3):

You want to get rid of transaction type and have two fields that total depending on being a debit or credit.

```
SELECT j.dtmInvoicedOn
, j.strJobKey
, c.strCustName
, Sum(Case When strTransactionType = 'credit' then r.dblTransactionAmount else 0 end) as credit
, Sum(Case When strTransactionType = 'debit' then r.dblTransactionAmount else 0 end) as debit   
FROM tbljobs AS j     
INNER JOIN tblreceivledger AS r ON j.strJobKey = r.strJobKey      
INNER JOIN tblcustomers AS c ON j.intCustomerID = c.intCustomerID      
WHERE c.strCustomerName = 'Acme Runners Inc'     
GROUP BY j.dtmInvoicedOn
, j.strJobKey
, c.strCustName
ORDER BY dtmInvoicedOn, strJobKey;
```